# How to check audio channel counts in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, swift3, avplayer

At the moment I am  trying to develop Online Video Playing App without storyboard. I able to play video on AVPlayer, but met issue with Audio Channels(All in one .mp4, not separated). Some of video has more than one (Like English, German etc). 
Here is Code example

```
 if let url  = URL(string: urlString){
            let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
            self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            playerLayer.frame = self.frame


            player.play()}
```

Question How to get count of audio channel numbers and and be able switch about them?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1: In your case, you can either get the [currentItem](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1387569-currentitem) asset:

```
player.currentItem.asset
```

or load an [AVURLAsset](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avurlasset) instead and use it with your AVPlayer.

2: This : [tracks(withMediaType:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avasset/1387140-tracks) should return an array from the `AVAsset` with your audio channels if you specify `AVMediaTypeAudio`.

3: You can then just check the number of objects in the array.

Comment: This is the number of tracks inside the audio files, not the number of channels..